# How to remove port 80 from the application URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-application

i want to create a new web application on port 80. but i need to allow the user to login to this web application without typing the port number. currently under the administration section i have the following:-

```
> Name:- SharePoint - SharePointDev80
> 
> URL:- http://sharepointdev:80/ 
> 
> Port:-  80
```

So does this mean that in-case the user wants to lo-gin tot the web application URL he have to type the port number.
second question how i can specify to use port 80 , but remove it from the URL ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you've created it on port 80, the user will not need to enter :80 in the url when they visit the site. Port 80 is the default port for HTTP web sites, and browsers will always assume it.

The 80 is shown in Central Administration for confirmation, as you can have web sites on ports other than 80.

Comment: but i can remove the port 80 from the public URL field, when creating new web application ? is that right ?. so the public URL for the web application will be "https://servername"??

Comment: Why do you want to? Your users won't need to add :80 to the URL so what's the problem?

Comment: but on my development environment under the central administration>>web application management. i have the application URL As http://servername , while inside the production environment the new web application which i created today, its URL is https://servername:80 ? so i am afraid if i continuous using the current configuration, then the users will have to type 80 in the URL . ?